# Calling once class from another.

Tags: java, selenium

I am learning java and I am stuck.  I am simply trying to run Open Amazon and have it do what is in both OpenAmazon and ClickLink.  In OpenAmazon is should open the browser and navigate to Amazon.  In ClickLink it is supposed to simply click on a link.  It opens the browser and goes to Amazon but then it gives me a null pointer exception (shown below)

I am trying to replicate the situation where, for example I would make a single login class that I can then call over and over for my test cases.

This is the class I am running:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OpenAmazon {

    WebDriver driver;

        public void invokeBrowser() {

            try {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get("http://amazon.in");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                OpenAmazon parentObj = new OpenAmazon();
                parentObj.invokeBrowser();
                ClickLink childObj = new ClickLink();
                childObj.getCommands();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the second class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class ClickLink {

    WebDriver driver;

    public void getCommands() {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Today's Deals")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e) on port 35812
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 11, 2018 8:33:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at co.edureka.selenium.webdriver.basic.ClickLink.getCommands(ClickLink.java:14)
    at co.edureka.selenium.webdriver.basic.OpenAmazon.main(OpenAmazon.java:28)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return the driver from `invokeBrowser()` and pass it into `ClickLink`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second class you have written doesn't have the driver information. To get this driver information from the first class you need to pass it via constructor

ClickLink should have the following constructor

`public ClickLink (WebDriver _driver){
driver=_driver
}`

In your main class you need to make change to the statement ClickLink childObj = new ClickLink(); as the following

```
ClickLink childObj = new ClickLink(driver);
```

Constructor documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
Dependency injection - http://rcardin.github.io/programming/software-design/java/scala/di/2016/08/01/resolve-problems-dependency-injection.html

Comment: Tej, Perfect!  Now I understand it and also thanks for the supplemental documentation.  Have a great day.